# Mailchimp needs 140kb to be loaded

Tags: jquery, performance, mailchimp

I use mailchimp to let users sign for a newsletter on my website. I just realized that mailchimp needs 140kb for that which is almost 10% of my landing page loadings.

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div class=" col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12 onewayDistance" ng-class="{'col-md-8 col-md-offset-2': !newsletterModal,'col-md_8':newsletterModal}" >
  <!--link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->
  <div id="mc_embed_signup" >
    <form action="//tripdelta.us8.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=9a2a27b15c44950e3ba360a28&amp;id=9b656d6732" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 " id="stayInformed">
          {{'STAY_INFORMED'|translate}} <span>{{'NEWSLETTER'|translate}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3 mc-field-group ">
          <input type="email" ng-model="userEmail" placeholder="{{'ENTER_EMAIL'|translate}}" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
          <div id="mce-responses" class="clear" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6)">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
          </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
          <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
            <input type="text"  name="b_9a2a27b15c44950e3ba360a28_9b656d6732" tabindex="-1" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-2" id="newsletterButton">
          <button type="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" ng-class="{'newsletterModalColor':newsletterModal}" class="button">{{'SUBSCRIBE'|translate}}</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'>
  </script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function($) {
      window.fnames = new Array();
      window.ftypes = new Array();
      fnames[0]='EMAIL';
      ftypes[0]='email';
    }(jQuery));
  var $mcj = jQuery;
  </script>
</div>
```

This is just normal code which i simply copied from their website and did some css changes. Any chance to minimize this amount of data to be loaded?

Comment: how is this related angularjs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there's JQuery API being downloaded from here:

//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js

So, if your website already use JQuery maybe you don't have to put this one.
But it seems they've modified it (i don't know exactly what is modified but it seems if you look trough all the code).

I can't think an other way to reduce the size right now :/

Comment: This library also includes validation logic for fields. Not including it will disable field validations.

Comment: Yup but i still think it's possible to remove some parts of the code, find those 'validation logic for fields' function, and crop all that you don't need, unless the js is generated for each 'client' it should be a good idea.

Comment: I'll try to remove anything possible. Thanks

Comment: It seems that that the jQuery code is strongly modified and taking it out does not seem to be possible....

Comment: Sorry to hear that then, maybe your best chance would be to send an e-mail to mailchimp hopefully they'll give you some hints :/.

Any way one sure things is that this link: http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js isn't minified, you could try to minify all the code at the bottom with http://jscompress.com/ for exemple ;)

Comment: It was really a mess, but I managed to get the necessary code out of the script....Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Dribel: can you please share the minified part? thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same problem. I just copied their mc-validate.js file to my wordpress site and load the local copy instead of the remote one. Since I have compression turned on in Apache by default, the library gets compressed automatically.

I then wrote a cron job to check daily if the file has changed, and download the new version if it has changed.

1. Create a directory under `wp-content` to store the library

   `mkdir wp-content/uploads/libraries`
2. Copy the library

   `cd wp-content/uploads/libraries`

   `wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js`
3. Change the URL where you load the script

   `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://yourwordpresssite.com/uploads/libraries/mc-validate.js'>
   </script>`

(Depending on your server settings, you may need `sudo` to accomplish the above.)

Comment: you are a ninja, sir

Answer (score 3):

Not my work, but you might like to look at this article:

https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-4-validating-mailchimp-subscribe-form/

This approach reduces mc-validate.js from 140kb (minified) to 9kb (minified) - "15.5× smaller than the version MailChimp provides".

The HTML replaces your existing MailChimp code. The JS and CSS files can, on the other hand, be hosted on (say) Google Drive:

- be careful to pick up the latest code ([here](https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/MorBEp) at the time of writing)
- copy the example JS and CSS code into separate files
- minify the files using -for example- [this](http://refresh-sf.com/) service
- create a public folder on your Google Drive
- upload the minified JS and CSS files to the folder
- share the JS and CSS files as public
- get a link to each file from Google Drive
- have it converted into a **download** link using -say- [this](http://www.hugestreet.info/p/direct-download-link-generator.html) service
- reference the generated links somewhere near the top of your main HTML file, remembering to replace the ampersand between 'download&ID='.

The final JS and CSS links should look something like:

```
<link href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=IDBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAHID' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script async='async' src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=IDBLAWBLAWBLAWBLAWBLAWBLAWID' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Works fine for me, allowing me to put a Mailchimp signup form into every Google Blogger post simply by adding the HTML block.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to resolve this problem is to load the local-mc-validate.js file on your web server and then replace the same with your javascript file.

This will get replaced by your link where you saved the file locally

//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js

Something like this

//www.xyz.com/js/mc-validate.js

Similarly, you should also need to upload the. CSS file locally on your server and replace the same with your link.

Reference: [Load MailChimp files locally](https://loveumarketing.com/how-increased-website-speed-drastically/#7_Load_Mail_Chimp_JavaScript_file_locally)