# Use cURL to download a file in a cron job

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, cron

I had come across another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739369/mailchimp-needs-140kb-to-be-loaded) where one guy talked about how he has his web server downloading a JS file from AWS on a routine basis using a cron job.  I haven't created a cron job before, but his routine is exactly what I need to implement.

I found out that my web host doesn't allow wget commands in cron jobs and they recommended that I use cURL instead.  Here's what I've got so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

> /usr/bin/curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron
>   https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js
>   --output wp-content/uploads/libraries/wp-content/uploads/libraries

Their documentation states that you need to declare a user agent (doesn't matter what it is) so that's why that's in there.

In a nutshell, I want it to download this file into that specific folder, keep the same file name, and overwrite the one that's already in there.

Am I even close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wget instead:

```
wget -O /virtualhosts/some-directory/wp-content/uploads/libraries/wp-content/uploads/libraries/mc-validate.js https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js
```

**EDIT:** Since your host doesn't support `wget` and does support `curl` you can use the curl exactly as you've posted, however for a cron job you'll likely want an absolute path to the file location:

```
curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js --output /absolute/path/to/mc-validate.js
```

^^ **note:** these are just fake absolute paths. You can run `pwd` from a shell to determine the actual absolute path to `wp-content/uploads/libraries/wp-content/uploads/libraries`.

Comment: `I found out that my web host doesn't allow wget commands in cron jobs`, first sentence in the second paragraph

Comment: @Antony: try using an absolute path to the location. Your cronjob is probably not running in the directory you've been testing in. By using an absolute path the `pwd` becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dave.  I tried this:

`curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js --output /wp-content/uploads/libraries/mc-validate.js`

and it gave me this error:

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

Warning: Failed to create the file
Warning: /wp-content/uploads/libraries/mc-validate.js
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16360)

Comment: ok. i don't think that's actually the absolute path to your wordpress installation. we need to find out where the `wp-content` directory is on the filesystem. do you have ssh access on this instance? if so can you go into the `wp-content` directory and type `pwd` and let me know what the output is?

Comment: You're a genius, Dave! It took me a while to figure out how to get SSH setup and then how to maneuver my way through things, but I was able to get the path. I tested everything and it was successful!! Here's the command with part of the path X'd out for security reasons in case anyone runs into something similar: `curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-valid‌​ate.js --output /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/uploads/libraries/mc-va‌​lidate.js`   Thanks again for your help!!